# how to access VAR_IN_OUT variable when FB cannot be extended?

Tags: codesys, structured-text

I have been trying to gain access to the `AXIS_REF_SM3` i.e. `Axis` of `SM3_Basic.MC_MoveAbsolute` in order to return the `wDriveId` of the axis.

Since `Axis` is declared as a `VAR_IN_OUT` variable, I am unable to access it outside of the FB using the `.Axis` syntax since it will cause the compiler to throw a

```
C0178:  No external access to VAR_IN_OUT parameter 'Axis' of 'MC_MOVEABSOLUTE'."
```

error which makes sense since `VAR_IN_OUT` variables are not supposed to be remotely accessible.

I then tried to extend the FB with `FUNCTION_BLOCK FB_MoveAbsolute EXTENDS SM3_Basic.MC_MoveAbsolute` and write my own method to return the `Axis` in the PRG calling `FB_MoveAbsolute` but I am getting the following compiler error

```
C0283:  Function block 'FB_MoveAbsolute': No override possible on Method MC_MoveAbsolute.FB_Init with access specifier FINAL
```

instead.

Does anyone know of a better way to get the `wDriveId` value of the `Axis` from `SM3_Basic.MC_MoveAbsolute`? 
Or some other way of checking which axis the FB is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to make a wrapper around the Function Block:

```hs
FUNCTION_BLOCK FINAL FinalBlock
VAR_IN_OUT
    someVar: DINT;
END_VAR
```

```hs
FUNCTION_BLOCK Wrapper
VAR_IN_OUT
    someVar: DINT;
END_VAR
VAR
    _wrapped_obj: POINTER TO FinalBlock;
END_VAR

_wrapped_obj^(someVar := someVar);

//////

METHOD FB_Init: BOOL
VAR_INPUT
    bInitRetains: BOOL;
    bInCopyCode: BOOL;
END_VAR
VAR_IN_OUT
    wrappedObj: FinalBlock;
END_VAR

THIS^._wrapped_obj := ADR(wrappedObj);

//////

METHOD GetSomeVarMethod : DINT

GetSomeVarMethod := THIS^.someVar;

//////

METHOD GetWrappedObjP : POINTER TO FinalBlock

GetWrappedObjP := THIS^._wrapped_obj;
```

```hs
PROGRAM SR_Main
VAR
    original: FinalBlock;
    someVar: DINT := 5;
    wrap: Wrapper(original);
    getVar: DINT;
END_VAR

wrap(someVar := someVar); // use this instead of "original(someVar := someVar);"
getVar := wrap.GetSomeVarMethod(); // getVar = 5
```

Edit: If you are going to use references (or pointers), 1 thing to watch out for is invalid reference exceptions. You'll get them in those 2 cases:

1. If you access the variable before setting it:

```hs
getVar := wrap.GetSomeVarMethod(); // calling this'll try to access someVar
wrap(someVar := someVar);
```

2. You forget that you should use the wrapper instead of the wrapped object:

```hs
original(someVar := someVar); // should have called "wrap(someVar := someVar);" instead!
getVar := wrap.GetSomeVarMethod();
```

To avoid that you can try:

1. Check the reference before accessing it:

```hs
METHOD GetSomeVarMethod : DINT

IF __ISVALIDREF(THIS^.someVar) THEN
    GetSomeVarMethod := THIS^.someVar;
ELSE
    GetSomeVarMethod := -1;
END_IF
```

or

```hs
TYPE OPTIONAL
STRUCT
    value: DINT;
    error: BOOL;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE

METHOD GetSomeVarMethod : OPTIONAL

IF __ISVALIDREF(THIS^.someVar) THEN
    GetSomeVarMethod.value := THIS^.someVar;
ELSE
    GetSomeVarMethod.error := TRUE;
END_IF
```

However, if the user forgets to call `wrap(someVar := someVar);` and only ever calls `original(someVar := someVar);` then someVar will forever be invalid.

2. Instead of passing the object to the wrapper, have the wrapper create and manage the object completely:

```hs
FUNCTION_BLOCK Wrapper
VAR_IN_OUT
    someVar: DINT;
END_VAR
VAR
        // with the 'no_init' attribute, we can let our FB_Init method initialize this object using user given arguments.
        // If FinalBlock doesn't have any custom initialization arguments, you can skip this attribute and the FB_init code below.
        {attribute 'no_init'}
    _wrapped_obj: FinalBlock;
END_VAR

_wrapped_obj(someVar := someVar);

//////

METHOD FB_Init: BOOL
VAR_INPUT
    bInitRetains: BOOL;
    bInCopyCode: BOOL;
    // FinalBlock initialization arguments
END_VAR

THIS^._wrapped_obj.FB_Init( (* initialization arguments *) );
```

Either way, I'd recommend having good documentation on how to properly use your wrapper and avoid mistakes.

Alternatively, if what you want is to pass the Function Block to a function and access the value of the VAR_IN_OUT variable inside that function, you can just pass that value alongside the Function Block (since if it is VAR_IN_OUT, you should have access to the original anyways):

```hs
VAR
    original: FinalBlock;
    someVar: DINT := 5;
END_VAR

original(someVar := someVar);
getVar := SomeFunction(obj := original, someVar := someVar);
```

or:

```hs
TYPE Bundle :
STRUCT
    obj: REFERENCE TO FinalBlock;
    someVar: REFERENCE TO DINT;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE

//////

VAR
    original: FinalBlock;
    someVar: DINT := 5;
    bun: Bundle(obj := original, someVar := someVar);
END_VAR

original(someVar := someVar);
getVar := SomeFunction(bundle := bun);
```

Comment: oh cool, I literally didn't think about just wrapping the FB, I don't suppose there is a way to prevent `FinalBlock` from being used as is with `INTERNAL` or something similar if you don't have access to the library source code right?

Comment: See the edit. TL; DR: You can have your wrapper create and fully manage the wrapped object without letting the user touch the wrapped object